# Find largest file by name in bash script

Tags: bash

I have json files with names

```
logtext.json
logtext.json.1
logtext.json.2
logtext.json.3
```

How to find file with greatest number with bash script?
In this case output should be "logtext.json.3"

Comment: 1.  `find` get list of filenames. 2. `sort` the filenames. 3. Get the last line `tail`.

Comment: Can the trailing number goes into two digits?

Comment: ls logtext.json.* | sort --version-sort | tail -1

Comment: @BartBarnard do  not parse the output of `ls`. Instead: `printf '%s\n' *.json.* | sort -rV | head -n1`. Here reverse sort allow use of `head` versus `tail` and it saves reading the whole stream until last line.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sort --version-sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

```
-V, --version-sort
    natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

```
find . -name "*.json*" | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1
```

---

If no `name` sort needs to be done, just use `ls`

```
ls | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1
```

---

`tail -n 1` limits the output to just 1 line

```sh
$ ls
file.json  file.json.1  file.json.15  file.json.3
$ find . -name "*.json*" | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1
./file.json.15
```

Answer (score 2):

I place an answer here without parsing the output of `ls` because this is a non-portable bad practice.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/310674

```sh
printf '%s\n' *.json* \
  | sort --reverse --version-sort \
  | head --lines=1
```

- `printf '%s\n' *.json*`: Produces a newline delimited stream of all files matching the `*.json*` pattern. This is portable and much more reliable than parsing the output of `ls`.
- `sort --reverse --version-sort`: Sorts the stream lines in reverse order, with version number sorting rules. This will place the highest version at the first line.
- `head --lines=1`: Prints the first line of the stream. Here it is preventing the read of the whole stream until the last line, since it stops at the first line.

If you use the GNU version of the utilities, you can process a `null` delimited list rather than a `newline` delimited list. This will allow handling of file names witch can contain `spaces`, `newlines` or other non-printable characters.

```sh
printf '%s\0' *.json* \
  | sort --reverse --version-sort --zero-terminated \
  | head --lines=1 --zero-terminated
```